# Invalid Write of Size when initialising variables (Valgrind and C)

Tags: c, valgrind

I am getting "Invalid write of size [1|4|8]" errors on lines where I initialise variables, when running valgrind on my code.

E.g.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#define size 50

int main()
{
  int i;

  bool valid = false; // error seen here
  int array[size];
  for(i = 0; i < size; i++) // error seen here
  {
    array[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

I am completely lost on this, so any help is much appreciated.
I am not sure if this could be related to `calloc()` calls elsewhere on the code, however valgrind is picking on every initialization line.

Comment: Post exact and complete code. Post exact and complete valgrind output.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to post production code ... so the snippet is best I can provide.

Comment: Doesn't have to be the full production code. Post a complete example that demonstrates the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: My bad that was a typo

Comment: That's why we ask you to post exact code that can reproduce the problem. You can't expect us to comment on code that probably doesn't even exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--max-stackframe` option in valgrind needs to be used to avoid blowing up stack which is causing the invalid reads/writes